# What am I doing with mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am aware of the [canonical question](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever) and have read it, yet I seem to be unable to find some stuff there.

Here are my conditions and rules to drop `www` and force `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I understand what I am trying to match. However the substitution rules are a bit unclear to me. What I don't understand is:

1. How did my hostname (without `www.`) end up in `%1`?
2. Why isn't the query string lost when the second rule is applied?

The reason behind the second question is that the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) explicitly states (highlighted by me):

> REQUEST_URI
>
> The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". **This notably excludes the query string** which is available as as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume these directives are working OK and you are just after an explanation as to why?

> 1. How did my hostname (without `www.`) end up in `%1`?

`%1` is a *backreference* to the first captured group in the last matched *CondPattern*. So, given the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
```

The regex (ie. *CondPattern*) `^www\.(.*)$` is matched against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable. The match is successful when `HTTP_HOST` satisfies the regex `^www\.(.*)$`, which is `www.` followed by *anything*. That *anything* is part of a captured group (parenthesised subpattern). ie. `(.*)`, not simply `.*`. Whatever matches the `(.*)` group is saved in the `%1` backreference and can be used later in the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. For example, given a request for `www.example.com/something`, this becomes:

```
RewriteCond www.example.com ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
```

`%1` will therefore contain `example.com`.

> Why isn't the query string lost when the second rule is applied?

Because, if you don't explicitly include a query string on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* then the query string from the request is *automatically* appended onto the end of the resulting *substitution*.

However, if you included a query string on the end of the *substitution*, even just an empty query string (a `?` followed by nothing), then the query string from the request is not appended. For example:

> ```
> RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
> ```

This will result in the query string being stripped from the request (note the trailing `?`). Alternatively, on Apache 2.4+ you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag to prevent the query string being appended.

*Aside:* I also removed the parentheses from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. You don't need a captured group here, since you are using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead. (This would be available in the `$1` backreference - note the `$` prefix. Storing backreferences when you don't need them is just waste of resources and hampers readability.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
> ```

I assume your server is behind a proxy server that is setting the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header?

Comment: Thank you for your explanations! Yes, I patched the directives from examples and they are working. I became suspicious because one rule consisted of %1 and $1 and the other included variables directly. It turned out useful as you revealed to me that i store a redundant reference in the last rule. Do I understand correctly that the `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$1`would behave the same in both rules and are different only because I got the parts from different examples? If so, how should one choose which to use? And to expand on query string - is anything else "automatically appended" or only that?

Comment: As to your last question - that document root is served over two domain names, let's say `example.org` and `assets.example.com`. The assets on `example.org` are included using `assets.example.com` domain name which points to a proxy that caches the assets. That's why I had to put two `RewriteCond`s there.

Comment: `%1` is a backreference to the last matched `RewriteCond` directive and `$1` is a backreference to the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. Using `%{REQUEST_URI}` or `$1` in this instance is largely a matter of preference. However, they are not necessarily the same - it depends on _context_. In a directory (incl. `.htaccess`) context then they are slightly different, however, in a server config/virtual host context they are probably the same.

Comment: eg. In `.htaccess` then a request for `example.com/path/to/file` would result in `REQUEST_URI` containing `/path/to/file`, but `$1` would contain `path/to/file` (note the missing slash prefix). This is consistent with your code example and from that I would assume you are in a directory (or `.htaccess`) context?

Comment: Yes, these are directives in a `.htaccess`.

Comment: Nothing else is "automatically appended". Btw, the same applies to `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` (mod_alias) directives. As regards which to use... `REQUEST_URI` or `$1`... `REQUEST_URI` is always the same, regardless of whether you are using server config or `.htaccess`. But it's not always possible to use `$1` like this (instead of `REQUEST_URI`), for example: `RewriteRule !^foo$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]` - this only redirects when the request is _not_ `/foo`. (It's not possible to have a captured group in a _negated_ regex.)